# MWS Amazon PHP API GetFulfillmentPreviewItemList: unclear how to set a list with more than one sku

Tags: php, xml, object, amazon-mws, fulfillment

there are two items.member in the array $order['Items.member'], only the last one appears in $itemList. first item[0] get apparently overwritten.

```
foreach ($order['Items.member'] as $lineitem) {

            $item[$v] = new FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_GetFulfillmentPreviewItem();
            $item[$v]->setSellerSKU($SKUselected);
            $item[$v]->setQuantity(round($lineitem['qty'],0));
            echo "qty: ".$lineitem['qty']."<br>";
            $item[$v]->setSellerFulfillmentOrderItemId($lineitem['SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId']);
            echo "SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId: ".$lineitem['SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId']."<br>";             

            $itemList->setmember($item[$v]);
            $v++;
        }
        $request->setItems($itemList);
        echo 'item0: <pre>';print_r($item[0]);echo '</pre>';
        echo 'item1: <pre>';print_r($item[1]);echo '</pre>';
        echo 'itemList: <pre>';print_r($itemList);echo '</pre>';
```

here the itemlist object dumped; filled only with last item 999938-1. The item 999938-0 is missing:

```
FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_GetFulfillmentPreviewItemList Object
(
    [_fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [FieldValue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_GetFulfillmentPreviewItem Object
                                (
                                    [_fields:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [SellerSKU] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldValue] => XX-XXXX-JRBG
                                                    [FieldType] => string
                                                )

                                            [Quantity] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldValue] => 1
                                                    [FieldType] => int
                                                )

                                            [SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [FieldValue] => 999938-1
                                                    [FieldType] => string
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [FieldType] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_GetFulfillmentPreviewItem
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

the items itself are defined correctly (as per echo).

I created already separate list as new object, however all items are supposed to send into a single fulfillment order eventually.

Now I am pretty much lost and looking into the model did not bring any clarification. this would be so easy with a loop just to create the XML code directly. lol

thank you for some hints

Answer (score 0):

ok the answer is pretty simple: introduction of another temporary array

```
$item[$v]->setSellerFulfillmentOrderItemId($lineitem['SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId']);

                $memberArray[] = $item[$v] ;


                $v++;
            }
            $itemList->setmember($memberArray);
            $request->setItems($itemList);
```

the list/array of member items must be given with the "setmember" function and not with "setItems". this is not intuitive and questionable naming, so it is not recommended to rely on names of functions.